# How to get object using Httpclient with response Ok in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

my web api like

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterUser(User user)
    {
        //User Implementation here

        return Ok(user);
    }
```

I am using HTTPClient to request web api as mentioned below.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
var result = await client.PostAsync( "api/users", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Where i can find user object in my result request which is implemented on client application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string Baseurl = GetBaseUrl(microService);
string url = "/client-api/api/token";

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())`enter code here`
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "5196810"));
    keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
    keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "abc.a@gmail.com"));
    keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "Sonata@123"));
    keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("platform", "FRPWeb"));


    HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";

    var result = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
    string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: Pass relative url in POSTAsync string Baseurl = GetBaseUrl(microService);
                string url = "/client-api/api/token";

Comment: Shouldnt use 'using' either for HttpClient.

Comment: @SeemaAs, Thank you very much !!, Your solution is working fine in my case.

**You saved my lot's of time.**

Answer (score 53):

You can use (depands on what you need), and de-serialize it back to user object.

```
await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
//or
await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
//or
await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Fe, if your web api is returning JSON, you could use

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>( await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

EDIT: 
as cordan pointed out, you can also add reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting` and use:

```
await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<User>()
```

Comment: Why not just use `await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<User>()`?

Comment: @cordan that is a solution too, but it needs extra reference to  `System.Net.Http.Formatting`

Comment: If you're using dotnet core, install [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) and you'll be good to go with `ReadAsAsync<T>()`.

Comment: This should be accepted answer really... don't you think?