# Returning an image using Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web service method, which looks like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<byte[]> Get(Guid id)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"Pictures\");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.Contains(id.ToString()))
        {
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is the client code, which is definitely working i.e. it is calling the web service and the web service is returning the image:

```
var response2 = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:59999/api/Images/5c60f693-bef5-e011-a485-80ee7300c692");
byte[] image2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190018/how-to-get-object-using-httpclient-with-response-ok-in-web-api
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("image.jpg", image2);
```

When I try to open image.jpg in Paint; it says it is an invalid file.  What is the problem?

Comment: The image picked up by the webervice, are you sure this is a jpg?

Comment: @D.J, I am certain.  I just checked.

Comment: ok, can you check if the bytearray received by the client is as long as the one send from the webservice ? maybe the image is not fully sent to the client

Comment: @D.J, the sizes of the byte arrays are different.  There is something wrong.  How do I get the image from the response? I cannot believe how difficult this is.

Comment: my first guess would be that the client doesn't receive the image but an error or info page, can you open url that is requested by the client in a browser ?

Comment: @DJ, a 200 OK status is received by the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to return file do not return `byte[]` from action because it gets `base64` encoded. You can decode `base64` string on client or better would be using `File` method in action

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult Get(Guid id)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"Pictures\");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.Contains(id.ToString()))
        {
            return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file), "image/jpeg");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @w0051977 with this answer client should be unchanged. Try it out

Comment: Are you saying use the client code in my original post? Thanks.