# How return a dictionary from WebAPI?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a MVC project that, from a view  upload one or more files to a server,
then , when i click submit a provate web service is recalled and i pass a collection of files to upload.
The upload workings fine, but form webapi i have an object (class Store) that i would return.

I do not know if I am wrong to return the "raw" object from the web api or wrong to read it.

this is my model

```cs
    public class Store
    {
        public IDictionary<string, string> dictionaryOfStores = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public string CodeText { get; set; }
    }
```

this i have my web api method:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<Store>> UploadAsync()
        {
            dictStores = new Store();
            foreach (var formFile in form.Files)
                    {

                        dictStores.dictionaryOfStores.Add(formFile.FileName, codefilename);
                        // also CodeText is filled here
                    }
                }
            }

            // return dictionary
            //

            return dictStores;
        }
```

this is my controller of mvc that recall private webservice

```cs
  public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(List<IFormFile> files)
        {

                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {

                            var model = new FilesViewModel();
                            MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                            foreach (var formfile in files)
                            {
                                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
                                byte[] data;
                                using (var br = new BinaryReader(formfile.OpenReadStream()))
                                    data = br.ReadBytes((int)formfile.OpenReadStream().Length);
                                ByteArrayContent bytes = new ByteArrayContent(data);

                                multiContent.Add(bytes, "file", formfile.FileName);
                                model.Files.Add(new FileDetails { Name = formfile.GetFilename() });
                            }
                            var result = await client.PostAsync("api/Load/Upload", multiContent); // 
                            // here i have try to read result.Content but doesn't have my data
                            var res = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                            // here i have to put res in my model
                            return View("Summary", model);

                    }
```

im use asp net core 2.2
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I solved by seeing the answer: [How to get object using Httpclient with response Ok in Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190018/how-to-get-object-using-httpclient-with-response-ok-in-web-api) 
I was able to read the data :

```cs
await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Store>()
```